# Переопределить свойство объекта ActiveRecord

Tags: php, yii2

Допустим, у меня есть 2 модели AR.
1. Payment - платежи
2. Cart - корзина

И соответственно у payment

```
 public function getCarts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cart::className(), ['payment_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Задача следующая. 
Мне необходимо корзину второго платежа слить с корзиной первого.

т.е.

```
$first_payment = Payment::findOne($first_payment_id);
$second_payment = Payment::findOne($second_payment_id);
```

И объединяем:

```
$first_payment->carts = array_merge($first_payment ->carts, $second_payment->carts);
```

И разумеется при таком подходе я ловлю ошибку:

```
Setting read-only property: frontend\models\Payment::carts
```

Что в принципе и логично.

Скажите, как лучше перезаписать это свойство?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($second_payment->carts as $cart) {
    $cart->payment_id = $first_payment_id;
    $cart->save();
}
```

Comment: мне не нужно делать никаких изменений в базе.

Comment: @РадикКамалов а зачем тебе тогда их понадобилось присваивать? О_о Просто сохрани в переменную результат мержа.

Comment: Дело в том, что данное присваивание выполняется не для всех payments. 
Хотелось, чтобы корзина была просто payment->carts, а не так, чтобы где-то $payments->carts, где-то $payment->custom_carts;

Comment: Присваивать необходимо для вывода. Короче, есть такие типы заказов, где заказа 2, но визуально для пользователя нужно показать только один, только объединить их корзины

Comment: @РадикКамалов ну хз тогда. Можешь просто отдельную переменную в классе сделать для этого. Перемудрил ты мне кажется.

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял задачу

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper; 

$first_payment = Payment::findOne($first_payment_id);
$first_array =  ArrayHelper::toArray($first_payment,[
    'frontend\models\Payment' => [
         'carts'=>'Carts',     
    ],
]);
$second_payment = Payment::findOne($second_payment_id);
$second_array = ArrayHelper::toArray( $second_payment,[
    'frontend\models\Payment' => [
         'carts'=>'Carts',     
    ],
]);

$merge_payment = ArrayHelper::merge( $first_array, $second_array);
```

в результирующем массиве в ячейке merge_payment['carts'] будет массив с ключами из свойств Carts ,в результате слияния  каждый ключ будет содержать массив двух значений.

Comment: Необходимо на выходе иметь тот же объект Payment. 
Получить массив не вызывает труда